# Can I use Azure AD in this scenario?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a client that wants us to accept SAML responses (this would be Azure AD). Azure AD will then take the SAML response and create a WS-FED token for our application to use.

Is this possible with Azure AD? It just needs to accept a SAML configuration from an external client, possibly do some transformations and forward to our app via WS-FED.

If Azure AD is not the right solution, are there any other recommendations? Other than identity server?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @TheWebGuy, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   As per the available authentication schemes in the market, currently **converting a WS-Fed token to a SAML endpoint token is possible but the vice versa is not. It is because SAML is much more advanced and reliable authentication mechanism than WS-Fed**. As ***`WS-Fed is only used by the Windows and related Microsoft on-premises backward compatible federation and identity providers like ADFS and Active Directory, it is a proprietary solution for Microsoft based products but the same is not relevant with SAML as it being an open-source standard for authentication and authorization of data between two parties`***.

As a result, **converting a SAML token to WS-Fed token may not be possible, hence I would suggest you to please refer the below link explaining how to exchange an ADFS SAMLv1 token for OAuth 2.0 token is described using the Postman/Microsoft graph as the orchestrator**: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion***

•   Thus, I would suggest you **upgrade your application’s authentication mechanism to SAML rather than WS-Fed since, if it supports WS-Fed, then it should also support SAML**. Also, regarding some doubts about **configuring the SAML/WS-Fed IdP federation in Azure AD for external identities**, kindly refer the below FAQ documentation regarding it for more detailed information: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation#frequently-asked-questions***